# подобие include c#, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Добрый день, есть TabPanel и 3 TabItem'a, кода в них довольно много, поэтому хочется их как-то разделить, возможно ли в c# сделать чтобы на каждый tabItem подгружалась отдельная страница (WPF Page)?

Comment: попроюуйте userControl или contenttemplate или так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796174/load-usercontrol-in-tabitem

Comment: А вот такой вариант не будет лучше? Если вообще убрать TabPanel и вместо этого добавить Frame и в него уже подгружать другие страницы  с главного  окна? Как будет лучше по производительности?

Comment: Я как понимаю когда в окне есть TabPanel, контент всех его вкладок грузится сразу не зависимо от того в какой из них ты находишься, а в случае с фреймом по отдельности. Или нет?:)

Comment: Можно и вкладки загружать не сразу, для этого нужно их инициализировать не в момент загрузки окна, а на событие переключения вкладки к примеру, ну или в любой момент когда вам будет удобно

Comment: То есть по большому счету без разницы как делать, главное чтобы самому было удобно? Просто проект не маленький, соединений с БД и прочей ерунды много, я думаю как бы все это дело не начало лагать. А в c# перебрался с Web'а буквально неделю назад, знаний в работе десктопных приложений нуль :(

Comment: ну лично на моем опыте лаги могут возникать если в таблице отображать очень большое количество записей, тут применяется разбиение по страницам или ленивая подгрузка, или же лаги были при использовании большого количества данных в диаграммах. В остальном лагов не наблюдал. View загружается в UI потоке, если долго грузятся данные тут нужно оптимизировать код или использовать busy indicator, загружая данные в отдельном потоке

Comment: `#include` здесь причем?

Comment: Странно, вы не путаете `TabPanel` и `TabControl`? `TabPanel` — это только заголовки табов для `TabControl`, а контент идёт отдельно.